# How to send one model with several classes in Ajax to update a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have this issue that I'm sure more experienced folks probably know how to resolve.

I have a class called CustomerProject. Inside this class, there are two other classes containing respective properties for each. One is Customer; the other is Project.

See code.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Customers
{
    [Serializable, DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class CustomerProjectDTO
    {
        public class Customer
        {

            [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
            [Display(Name = "ID")]
            [DataMember]
            public short CustomerID { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(256)]
            [DataMember]
            public string UserName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(50)]
            [EmailAddress]
            [DataMember]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [StringLength(50)]
            [DataMember]
            public string Company { get; set; }

            [StringLength(50)]
            [DataMember]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [StringLength(50)]
            [DataMember]
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            [StringLength(50)]
            [DataMember]
            public string Address1 { get; set; }

            [StringLength(50)]
            [DataMember]
            public string Address2 { get; set; }

            [StringLength(50)]
            [DataMember]
            public string City { get; set; }

            [StringLength(2)]
            [DataMember]
            public string State { get; set; }

            [StringLength(10)]
            [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
            [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Must match 99999 or 99999-9999 format")]
            [DataMember]
            public string Zip { get; set; }

            [StringLength(12)]
            [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
            [RegularExpression(@"^\s*([\(]?)\[?\s*\d{3}\s*\]?[\)]?\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{3}\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Must match 999-999-9999 format")]
            [DataMember]
            public string HomePhone { get; set; }

            [StringLength(12)]
            [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
            [RegularExpression(@"^\s*([\(]?)\[?\s*\d{3}\s*\]?[\)]?\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{3}\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Must match 999-999-9999 format")]
            [DataMember]
            public string CellPhone { get; set; }

            [StringLength(100)]
            [DataType(DataType.Url)]
            [DataMember]
            public string Website { get; set; }

            [StringLength(50)]
            [DataType(DataType.Url)]
            [DataMember]
            public string IMAddress { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
            [Display(Name = "Created")]
            [DataMember]
            public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Updated")]
            [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
            [DataMember]
            public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        }

        public class Project
        {

            [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
            [Editable(false)]
            [Display(Name = "Proj ID")]
            [DataMember]
            public short ProjectID { get; set; }

            [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
            [Editable(true)]
            [Display(Name = "Cust ID")]
            [DataMember]
            public short CustomerID { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
            [StringLength(30)]
            [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
            [DataMember]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
            [DataMember]
            public string Description { get; set; }

            [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
            [Display(Name = "Category")]
            [DataMember]
            public short CategoryID { get; set; }

            [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
            [Display(Name = "Priority")]
            [DataMember]
            public short PriorityID { get; set; }

            [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
            [Display(Name = "Status")]
            [DataMember]
            public short StatusID { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
            [DataMember]
            public decimal? Quote { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
            [DataMember]
            public string Notes { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
            [Display(Name = "Created")]
            [DataMember]
            public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
            [Display(Name = "Updated")]
            [DataMember]
            public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

If I'm using Code Frist EF 6.1 approach and using the **HTML.BeginForm** methodology inside an MVC Controller, I have no problem sending the data into a Create method and saving the data for both classes with the above code.

If I'm using an **Ajax approach in JavaScript**, I had to combine the properties of the two child classes into one class with unique property names. I also had stringify all of the properties while sending over the data. It updated just fine, but **I was wondering if there is a similar way I can do it with the Ajax Javascript approach with using the child classes (as in the first approach)** ( see one class and ajax code below).

See code below.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Customers
{
    [Serializable, DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class CustomerProjectDTO
    {
        //Customer

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display(Name = "ID")]
        [DataMember]
        public short customer_CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(256)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [EmailAddress]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_Email { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_Company { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_FirstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_LastName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_Address1 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_Address2 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_City { get; set; }

        [StringLength(2)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_State { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Must match 99999 or 99999-9999 format")]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_Zip { get; set; }

        [StringLength(12)]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\s*([\(]?)\[?\s*\d{3}\s*\]?[\)]?\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{3}\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Must match 999-999-9999 format")]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_HomePhone { get; set; }

        [StringLength(12)]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\s*([\(]?)\[?\s*\d{3}\s*\]?[\)]?\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{3}\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Must match 999-999-9999 format")]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_CellPhone { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_Website { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_IMAddress { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Created")]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime customer_CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Updated")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? customer_UpdatedDate { get; set; }


        //Project

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Editable(false)]
        [Display(Name = "Proj ID")]
        [DataMember]
        public short project_ProjectID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Editable(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Cust ID")]
        [DataMember]
        public short project_CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
        [StringLength(30)]
        [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
        [DataMember]
        public string project_Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [DataMember]
        public string project_Description { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Category")]
        [DataMember]
        public short project_CategoryID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Priority")]
        [DataMember]
        public short project_PriorityID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        [DataMember]
        public short project_StatusID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [DataMember]
        public decimal? project_Quote { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [DataMember]
        public string project_Notes { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Created")]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime project_CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Updated")]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? project_UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    }
}

function createCustomerProject()
{
    var currdate = new Date();
    var currdate = (currdate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + currdate.getDate() + '/' + currdate.getFullYear() + ' ' + currdate.getHours() + ':' + currdate.getMinutes() + ':' + currdate.getSeconds();

    var customerProject_Input = {
        customer_UserName: $('#customer_UserName').val(),
        customer_Email: $('#customer_Email').val(),
        customer_Company: $('#customer_Company').val(),
        customer_FirstName: $('#customer_FirstName').val(),
        customer_LastName: $('#customer_LastName').val(),
        customer_Address1: $('#customer_Address1').val(),
        customer_Address2: $('#customer_Address2').val(),
        customer_City: $('#customer_City').val(),
        customer_State: $('#customer_State').val(),
        customer_Zip: $('#customer_Zip').val(),
        customer_HomePhone: $('#customer_HomePhone').val(),
        customer_CellPhone: $('#customer_CellPhone').val(),
        customer_Website: $('#customer_Website').val(),
        customer_IMAddress: $('#customer_IMAddress').val(),
        customer_CreatedDate: currdate,
        customer_UpdatedDate: null,
        project_Name: $('#project_Name').val(),
        project_Description: $('#project_Description').val(),
        project_CategoryID: $('#project_CategoryID').val(),
        project_PriorityID: $('#project_PriorityID').val(),
        project_StatusID: $('#project_StatusID').val(),
        project_Quote: $('#project_Quote').val(),
        project_Notes: $('#project_Notes').val(),
        project_CreatedDate: currdate,
        project_UpdatedDate: null
    };

    var Url = $("#customerprojectCreateUrl").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: Url,
        //data: AddAntiCSRFToken(JSON.stringify(customerProject_Input)),
        data: JSON.stringify(customerProject_Input),
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
```

### EDIT

```
New model:
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using YeagerTechDB.Models;

namespace YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Customers
{
    [Serializable, DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class CustomerProjectDTO
    {
        public Customer customer { get; set; }

        public Project project { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Screenshot of JS data:
[image]

Screenshot of controller data right after call to JS:
[image]

Stephen, the data in the Controller right after the JS is null. I'm obviously doing something wrong the way I'm serializing it in the JS.

I'm using the full Ajax methodology.

Please take the screen shots of mine and view in your favorite image viewer and look at my JS. What am I doing wrong in there not being able to pass the data to my controller correctly?

Thanks so much for your insight...

### EDIT #3

Stephen, I've included the entire View for the Create....

```
@model YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Customers.CustomerProject


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Customer & Project";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<div class="body-content">
    <h4>Customer/Project</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Customer</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "UserName" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.Company, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Company" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer.Company, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "First Name" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Last Name" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.Address1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Address1" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer.Address1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.Address2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Address2" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer.Address2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "City" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.State, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "State" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.Zip, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Zip" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer.Zip, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.HomePhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Home Phone" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer.HomePhone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.CellPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Cell Phone" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer.CellPhone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.Website, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Website" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer.Website, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.IMAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "IM Address" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer.IMAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Project</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.project.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "ProjectName" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.project.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Description" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.project.CategoryID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryDescription"), "-- Select Category --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project.CategoryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.project.PriorityID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Priorities, "PriorityID", "PriorityDescription"), "-- Select Priority --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project.PriorityID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.project.StatusID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Statuses, "StatusID", "StatusDescription"), "-- Select Status --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project.StatusID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.project.Quote, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Quote" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project.Quote, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.project.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Notes" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <button type="submit" id="btnCustomerProjectCreate" class="btn btn-primary col-offset-2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    @Html.Hidden("customerprojectCreateUrl", Url.Action("Create", "CustomerProjects", new { area = "Customers" }))
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            if (typeof contentCreateCustomerProject == "function")
                contentCreateCustomerProject();
        });
    </script>
}
```

### EDIT 4

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using YeagerTechDB.Models;

namespace YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Customers
{
    [Serializable, DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class CustomerProjectDTO
    {
        public Customer customer { get; set; }

        public Project project { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Create(CustomerProjectDTO customerProject)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    await db.AddCustomerProjectAsync(customerProject);
  }
  return View(customerProject);
}
```

### JS

```
var customerProject_Input = $('#form1').serialize();
var Url = $("#customerprojectCreateUrl").val();

$.ajax({
  url: Url,
  //data: AddAntiCSRFToken(JSON.stringify(customerProject_Input)),
  data: JSON.stringify(customerProject_Input),
  dataType: "html",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  async: true,
```

### VIEW

```
@model YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Customers.CustomerProjectDTO
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Create Customer & Project";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
<div class="body-content">
  <h4>Customer/Project</h4>
  <hr />
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Customer</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "UserName" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Use a view model containing 2 properties (`Customer` and `Project`). Render you controls using strongly typed helpers (`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.UserName)` etc), then `$.post('@Url.Action("yourAction", "yourController")', $(yourForm).serialize(), function(result) {...})`. There is no need to build the object manually.

Comment: Stephen, when serializing the form and after I receive it in my DB logic layer, I am expecting a type of "CustomerProject". Will this still work expecting this type?

Comment: Yes, if your action method signature is `public ActionResult Edit(CustomerProject model)`, then model will be correctly bound with all your form values.

Comment: Stephen, according to my edit, if I just include the following in the JS: "data: $('#form1').serialize()," or if I leave out the "JSON.stringify", it doesn't even make it to my Controller...

Comment: Difficult to read the images, but it looks like `.serialize()` is working OK - I can see `customer.UserName=someValue&customer.Email=someValue&....`(and your don't need `JSON.stringify`). If its not hitting the controller, what error messages are you getting in the browser console? (or is it hitting the controller but the values are not binding?). And I see you have `RedirectToAction()` in the POST method which is pointless since its an ajax call (ajax calls stay on the same page so it will never redirect) - in which case why are you even using ajax?

Comment: I also see that you have properties in your models such as `customer_UserName` which means the the data that gets posted back would need to be `customer.customer_UserName` (not `customer.Email`) so either your manually generating your html or making some other major error generating your html.

Comment: It's hitting the controller, but the Customer & Project objects inside the customerProject variable are null. Copy the images and view them in your favorite image viewer for better detail. The "dataType" is "html" in the Ajax call. It does return to the Index page with the newly added Customer/Project. I'd rather do it via the MVC BeginForm statement, but many companies refuse to use that and strictly use it via Ajax calls in JavaScript.

Comment: btw, you are right with the Ajax. The redirect will never be hit.... It obviously stays on the page. I have a "Back to List" link which brings you back to the Index page with the newly added cust/proj.

Comment: You need to address the naming of the controls - the names have no relationship to your model. Show a small snippet of the view. (And there is absolutely no point using ajax in this case - if anything its degrading performance). It also seems you have some kind of relationship between `Project` and `Customer` based on `public short project_CustomerID { get; set; }` - in which case why does `Project` not contain `public Customer customer { get; set; }`?

Comment: Stephen, I've included the entire View for the Create.

Comment: But you model is `CustomerProject` but your method signature is `CustomerProjectDTO`! Change the signature to `public ActionResult Create(CustomerProject model)` (not sure why you would use async here if all you making is a database call to save the data)

Comment: I changed the model to "@model YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Customers.CustomerProjectDTO", and left the signature to public ActionResult Create(CustomerProjectDTO model). I'm still getting null values for the Customer & Project classes when I get into the Controller.

Comment: Is it anything in the way I'm passing the data in the ajax call to the controller that is the issue?

Comment: I've modified the posts for the "Creates" to simply remove the redirect as after the Ajax call is done, it will stay on the page. As for the Edits, I have a "data-url" statement attached to the "Edit" button. On a successful Ajax call, that redirects to the Index page. As I mentioned before, most companies unfortunately shy away from using the ASP.Net MVC implementation of the Beginform & AjaxBeginForm because they want to decouple that from only a specific JS Ajax call. It's unfortunate, but that's the way I've seen most companies do it.

Comment: You have me totally  confused. Your first 3 code snippet shows different models for `YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Customers.CustomerProjectDTO`  (I'm not sure which one your even using).

Comment: Take a look at my EDIT #4, These are the ones I'm using. thanks for your patience. I'd really like to get this concept down for simply serializing a form instead of writing each property out. I really think it has something to do with the way I'm formatting the data in the Ajax call before it gets to the Controller.

Comment: Have you considered Ajax.BeginForm?

Comment: You do not need `JSON.stringify()` just `data: $('#form1').serialize();` will work (assuming you do have a containing element with `id="#form1`). If the only control in that container was the `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.UserName` then `console.log($('#form1').serialize()); will output `customer.UerName=someValue` which will correctly bind to the model. But if your not using `Html.BeginForm()` to generate the `<form>` tag, using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` is a bit pointless if your expecting client side validation

Comment: progrAmmar, as mentioned before, the company I'm working for prohibits the use of internal asp.net mvc BeginForm and Ajajx.BeginForm in the View. They want it totally decoupled from the View in a separate JS file using an Ajax call for every GET/POST.

Comment: Still doesn't work Stephen. Didn't even get to the Controller. btw, the JS method "form.valid()" will throw any unobtrusive JS validation errors I have with my dataannotations on my model. I've tried another process very similar to what we are tying to do. I created JS Customer & Project objects and populated them with the ID's from the generated View.  I then populated the JS object "customerProject_Input" with just those two previous objects: customer: customer, project: project and stringified those. It made it to the Controller, the objects were non-null, but no values were showing up.

Comment: I've exhausted all the space here I can for this thread. I'm going to create a new thread with just the last comment and the code being used to start fresh. With this approach, hopefully, something will stand out very easily...

Answer (score 0):

```
traditional: true,
data: JSON.stringify({
     model: {
                 "Column1": $("#Column1").val(),
                 "Column2": $("#Column2").val(),
                 "Column3": $("#Column3").val(),
                 "Column4": $("#Column4").val(),
           }),
```

in yours add map value like this and should be very helpful to you.

Comment: this works exactly how I had it before, but I had to combine properties from both Customer & Project into 1 data model with one class. This whole exercise was trying to separate the classes and feed them into the Controller as long as the controller had the same signature...

Comment: If there's no way to send the data through using 1 superclass with multiple child classes, then so be it. I'll simply combine all the fields in one class (combining all the properties from the different classes) as it is working as I originally had it.

Comment: data: JSON.stringify({
    superclass :{ 
  Customer: {
                 "Column1": $("#Column1").val(),
                 "Column2": $("#Column2").val(),                
           }),
 Project  :{
                 "Column1": $("#Column1").val(),
                 "Column2": $("#Column2").val(),               
           }),
}

Comment: can you try this and to controller define same module object name that you pass in ajax , suppose your ajax object module name is {superclass} then you should classify the name in controller like is {superclass}

Comment: You have the right idea, but I was hoping there was a tool out there like JSON.Net; only in reverse. Instead of converting .Net objects to JSON, I was hoping there was a tool to convert JSON to .Net objects within javascript. As I said before, it works fine if I just create 1 .Net class and combine all the properties of the child classes into that one .Net class. So, unless there's a tool that can do what I said, I'm sticking to what I just mentioned.